# Subtraction in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm doing an inventory, and I have part of the code working correctly:

```
def add_art_view(request, pk, template_name='invstock/art_form.html'):
    id = get_object_or_404(Stock, pk=pk)
    form = StockForm(request.POST or None, instance=id)

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, ('Register Edited Successfully'))
        return redirect('invstock:art_list_view')

    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <h2><a href="{% url 'invstock:art_list_view' %}">ART FORM</a></h2>
            <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label>Cantidad</label>{{ form.cantidad}}
                     <label>Cantidad a debitar</label>{{ form.var_resta}}
                     <label>Name</label>{{ form.name}}
                     <label>ID</label>{{ form.id}}
                 </div>

                 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>

{% endblock %}
```

```
class StockForm(forms.ModelForm):

    var_resta = forms.DecimalField(initial= Decimal('0'), decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
    name = forms.CharField(initial="None",)

    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields = [
            'id',
            'cantidad',
            'name',
            'var_resta',
        ]
```

```
class Stock(models.Model):

    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    cantidad = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
    var_resta = models.DecimalField(default=Decimal('0'), decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
    name = models.CharField(default="None",max_length=100)
```

My intention is: to subtract the CANTIDAD field minus the VAR_RESTA field but from the views, and store the resulting value in the CANTIDAD field, something like
CANTIDAD = CANTIDAD - VAR_RESTA, I have dilated for weeks this, because in all the research, videos, courses, I have not been able to find the answer, you can only analyze how to do it from the template, but it is not what I need.
I Have found some examples like {{ myval|add:"-5" }}, or creating a template tag but this is far from what i want to do.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: There's not enough information here to know how to answer. Can you post the definition of your form and maybe your model or the relevant fields thereof? Is "AMOUNT" a field in your model? (because it doesn't appear to be defined anywhere in what you posted).

Comment: It's not clear what you want. No where in your code is there an `AMOUNT` field. Please explain what your application is doing (some context always helps to understand the problem), what should happen when the form is posted, what your model looks like and what you want to save to the database.

Comment: Show your model that has the field `var_resta` and `cantidad`

Comment: What's the high-level definition of what you are trying to do? If it's "display an object and get a number `var_resta` from the user, subtract that  from a field of the object, and store the object back in the database" then IMO you are better off just using a plain form (not modelform) with one numeric field and passing the object to be updated to the template (as well as the form) so rendering can display anything in the object.

Comment: @nigel222 I'm building a simple inventory app, so what i'm triying to do is let the user specify the amount to be subtracted from the inventory.  Let's say i have in the database 20 apples stored in the CANTIDAD field, then there will be another field VAR_RESTA where the user will input the amount to be subtracted, let's say he is going to subtract 5 apples, the final result will be 15 apples that must be stored in the CANTIDAD field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still not entirely clear, but whenever you want to do some custom processing on a model instance beyond what the ModelForm does (which is simply storing the valid data from the form), then you use the sequence

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save( commit=False)
    # now update the object further
    ...         
    obj.save()  # commit the (altered) obj to the database
```

I'm slightly confused by what you have posted because `var_resta` appears to be a field of the model from the `Meta` in the `ModelForm`. Somehow it doesn't feel right to be doing

```
    obj.cantidad = obj.cantidad - obj.var_resta
```

but that's how the question reads. I'm guessing perhaps var_resta should perhaps be an additional field declared in the `ModelForm` but not a field of the table in the database, in which case it would be

```
    obj.cantidad = obj.cantidad - form.cleaned_data['var_resta']
```

[update]

OK, it's now clearer. See the comments on the question. I'd suggest that this is not a case for using a ModelForm at all, since only one field on the object is to be updated, and not by directly copying a number input by the user. Instead, just a vanilla form with the one field to obtain `var_resta`.

```
class StockForm(forms.Form):

    var_resta = forms.DecimalField(initial= Decimal('0'), decimal_places=2, max_digits=5
```

And in the view:

```
def add_art_view(request, pk, template_name='invstock/art_form.html'):
    id = get_object_or_404(Stock, pk=pk)
    form = StockForm(request.POST or None )

   context = {
        'form': form, 
        'id':id
    }

    if form.is_valid():
        id.cantidad = id.cantidad - form.cleaned_data['var_resta']
        id.save() 
        messages.success(request, ('Register Edited Successfully'))
        return redirect('invstock:art_list_view')

    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

The template context now contains the object `id`, so it can display to the user its current name `{{id.name}}`, cantidad `{{id.cantidad}}` etc. but the user cannot input changed values for these.

This is all untested and I expect there are errors.

Comment: well the reason i did not post the models was cuz i thought the form always has the same fields as the model, as you can see i added the models.py now, and yes i have the VAR_RESTA in my models . . .

Comment: I will check around it and play with the code to see what's happens, i really have tried several things for weeks, still no success, hopes this helps. Thanks!